# PCLCrypto 'PInvoke.NTStatusException' STATUS_DATA_ERROR

Tags: pcl-crypto

> Exception thrown: 'PInvoke.NTStatusException' in PInvoke.Kernel32.DLL
>        Additional information: NT_STATUS error: STATUS_DATA_ERROR (0xC000003E)

Hi,
 I keep getting this error every so often when I try to decrypt and I have no idea what it means.

I am using `Encoding.Unicode.GetString` and `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` to write/read the encrypted string in a file.

The full stacktrace is below:

> at PInvoke.Kernel32Extensions.ThrowOnError(NTSTATUS status)
>        at PInvoke.BCrypt.BCryptDecrypt(SafeKeyHandle hKey, Byte[] pbInput, Void*pPaddingInfo, Byte[] pbIV, BCryptEncryptFlags dwFlags)
>        at PCLCrypto.SymmetricCryptographicKey.Decrypt(Byte[] ciphertext, Byte[] iv)
>        at PCLCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(ICryptographicKey key, Byte[] data, Byte[] iv)
>        at Myapp.filename.d__13.MoveNext()

Answer (score -1):

+2 I'm getting petty much the same issue - I found from another post on Xam forums that I should be using Unicode that solved the last padding error but this then popped ip.

> trace = {PInvoke.NTStatusException: NT_STATUS error: STATUS_DATA_ERROR
>   (0xC000003E)    at PInvoke.Kernel32Extensions.ThrowOnError(NTSTATUS
>   status)    at PInvoke.BCrypt.BCryptDecrypt(SafeKeyHandle hKey, Byte[]
>   pbInput, Void* pPaddingInfo, Byte[] pbIV, BCryptEncryptFlags dwFlags) 
>   at PCLCrypto.SymmetricCryptographicKey.Decrypt(Byte[] ciphertext,
>   Byte[] iv)    at
>   PCLCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(ICryptographicKey key, Byte[]
>   data, Byte[] iv)

FWIW this is on a PCL project and occurs when running UWP on the local machine - haven't yet tried it on Android

I notice your post was less than a month ago - I do hope someone can help PCLcrypto is so straightforward to use otherwise

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: well spotted Sherlock, that's why I put +2 but I was trying to add to the info

Comment: I commented that because this is itself is an error you got but the question OP asked doesn't get answered through you posting this. Therefore, it doesn't qualify as an answer to the question. You should consider adding this as a comment.

Comment: Any update on this issue?